# Can no longer drag photos to desktop

Tags: macos, google-chrome, mojave

I used to be able to drag images to my desktop. This now seems broken. Here's a [video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VJ24Cb23Lq2wAVhmRYAM8F3IcF3-wLn-/view?usp=sharing) of the problem. Basically, I'll drag an image (doesn't matter from where) to my desktop and it will not appear as a file.

Note: I have tried relaunching finder with `cmd+alt+esc` and with the terminal commands:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder CreateDesktop true
killall Finder
```

Model Identifier: MacBookPro11,4

System Version: macOS 10.14 (18A391)

Comment: is that your desktop ?

Comment: Yes. What is in the video is me dragging a photo onto the desktop